# Why don’t all real roots come in pairs?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

The conjugate root theorem states that for a polynomial p(x) with rational coeficients, if there exists a complex root a+bi then a-bi must also be a root of p(x).

However all real numbers can be reprosented as complex numbers with the complex component b=0, so if to the polynomial p(x), a+0i is a root then a-0i is also a root meaning that p(x) has a root “a” with multiplicity 2?

I there is a reason to why this is wrong because many counter exaplmes are out there but i dont know that reason, hence i ask why is this wrong?

Comment: The theorem makes no claims that $a$ is a repeated root.

Comment: The conjugate root theorem is about polynomials with *real* coefficients, it's not a theorem about multiplicity, real roots are their own conjugate and thus trivially satisfy the theorem.

Comment: "If $1$ is a root, then $1$ is a root" is a borderline tautological statement that the conjugate root theorem implies. It gives you no new information (nor is it a statement about multiplicity).

Comment: your "two" roots $a+0i$ and $a-0i$ are really just one root $a$ which is trivially equal to $a$.

Answer (score 3):

All the theorem says is if $a+ci$ is a root then $a-ci$ is a root.

That is all it says.

It doesn't say *anything* about them being *different* roots or each iteration accounts different degrees of the polynomial.

If $c\ne 0$ then $a+ci\ne a-ci$ so they *can't* be the same root and they must each account for degrees of the polynomial.  We derive that from the simple fact that $a+ci\ne a-ci$.  We do not derive it from the theorem at all.

But if $a+0i$ and $a-0i$ are roots we have $a+0i=a-0i$ so they *can* be the same root and contribute only to *one* degree of the polynomial.  There is *nothing* in the theorem that says $a+0i$ and $a-0i$ must differ and that there must be a double root.

In a way it's like if we that if say in a family "A and B both have a brother".  And we conclude there are two boys.  That is valid if $A$ or $B$ is boy.  But if they are both girls then we never actually said they had *different* brothers.

$a+ci$ and $a-ci$ are roots.  But we never said they were *different* roots.